# Youtube Search API limit

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to use the Youtube REST API to retrive videos, channels etc.

When using the 
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search to retrivew videos by a keyword i am initially getting 50 records with a nextpage token. Inturn using the nextpage token continuosly to get more records.

But after some iterations (may be 10-12) nextpagetoken is not coming.

Is there any limitations on the number of records that can be retrieved.
Number of records that are retrieved are not consistent too. For vidoes i am getting around 560 and for channels i am getting 570+.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: information about quotas and rate limiting are in the documentation. You don't show any code to replicate a problem

Comment: May be there are not more videos available for your query .. that's why no token is returned to load next set of results.

Comment: Hey, i just asked a questions concerning the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294586/youtube-search-list-does-not-return-any-items-after-9-pages
Did you figured it out yet?

Comment: Have the same experience, I can only get 20 pages. Tried this multiple times with different searches but cannot get more than 19 nextPageTokens. I use 50 items per query. So I cannot get more than 20*50 == 1000 items

Answer (score 0):

Simply put there is a 50 video limit.

There a method for getting around this for video results on one page and that is by sending 2 requests.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=YOURYOUTUBEUSERNAME&max-results=50

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=YOURYOUTUBEUSERNAME&max-results=50&start-index=50
```

If you notice, one is calling for the first 50 and the second is calling 50 start index at video 50.