# youtube.search.list does not return any items after 9 pages

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get a list of many youtube Channels.

After i got around 400 results (8 pages x 50 results/page), i call the 8th oder 9th page via:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&maxResults=50&pageToken=CJADEAE&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

i get only 16 results and from this point on the next 10 (or something) nextPageTokens return no items at all and after the 19th nextPageToken there is not even a nextPageToken in the response.

Nevertheless the query says "totalResults": 1000000, "resultsPerPage": 50.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `serch` call is restricted. As it will start to return duplicates after a while, and it is almost an infinite number of possible results. So they have chosen to cap that search term.